# Is there a way to programmatically detect memory leaks in process heap?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

There's [_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/d41t22sb.aspx) in Visual C++ runtime heap. Is there any similar function or other programmatically accessible infrastructure for the process heap (the heap returned by `GetProcessHeap()` function)?

Comment: Windbg can dump the heap at process exit, but it won't tell you who allocated the blocks.